# Rails Print JSON with Class Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5.0 API and trying to have a `print_it` class method that runs `as_json` on an object. (I need a separate method to put complex logic into later)

Whenever I test it, it errors with:

`NoMethodError (undefined method print_it for #<Class:0x007f7b7b092f20>):`

In Model: project.rb

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
      def print_it
        self.as_json
      end
end
```

In controller: projects_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::ProjectsController < Api::ApiController
    def index
        render json: Project.print_it
    end
end
```

How can I use `print_it` on an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Project.print_it
```

is calling `print_it` on the class `Project`. But, you define `print_it` as an instance method, not a class method, here:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  def print_it
    self.as_json
  end
end
```

You probably want something more like:

```
class Api::V1::ProjectsController < Api::ApiController
  def index
    render json: @project.print_it
  end
end
```

Naturally, you'll need to set `@project`.

To use `print_it` on an `ActiveRecord_Relation` called `@projects`, you *could* do something like:

```
@projects.map{|p| p.print_it}
```

You'll end up with an `array`.

But that *might* be expensive, depending on the number of projects and the nature of `print_it`.

> How can I use print_it on an object?

You **are** 'using' (calling) `print_it` on an object. `Project` is an object. Just like `@project` is an object. You just happen to be calling `print_it` on an object that doesn't have `print_it` defined (thus the `undefined method` error).

I will also note that [Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/j%c3%b6rg-w-mittag) wishes to say:

> I am one of those Ruby Purists who likes to point out that there is no such thing as a class method in Ruby. I am perfectly fine, though, with using the term *class method* colloquially, **as long as it is fully understood by all parties that it is a colloquial usage**. In other words, if you *know* that there is no such thing as a class method and that the term "class method" is just short for "instance method of the singleton class of an object that is an instance of `Class`", then there is no problem. But otherwise, I have only seen it obstruct understanding.

Let it be fully understood by all parties that the term *class method* is used above in its colloquial sense.

Comment: When I use `@projects.print it`,  it returns `NoMethodError (undefined method print_it for #<Project::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f9bc9398930>)`

Comment: `@projects` is a collection (more specifically, an `ActiveRecord_Relation`, as indicated). You define `print_it` on an instance of `Project`. So, you can't call `print_it` on the collection. Which is what the error is telling you.

Comment: So, how would I `print_it` a collection. The only way I've found so far is making it an instance method `print_it(@projects)` - is that a proper way of achieving the result?

Comment: Updated with answer.

Comment: That works, but yes it is very expensive. I think `print_it(@projects)` should be less expensive as it uses a custom `as_json` parser we've installed..

Comment: 'Should' being the operative term. You could benchmark and find out.